# Shell # inside (( ))

Tags: shell

I am new to shell. I am not quite understand the following function. This function basically increase the hour by 1.

I am wondering why the developer put "10#" in front of $g_current_hour+1. From my understanding, dose # in shell means comments?

```
f_increment_hour() {
    g_next_hour=$((10#$g_current_hour+1))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything depends on the context. Here `10#` means base 10.

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.  A
>   leading 0x or 0X denotes hexadecimal.  Otherwise, numbers take  the 
>   form  [base#]n,  where  the optional base is a decimal number between
>   2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that
>   base.  If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used.

Comment: +1: Note that the Open Group sh language specification states: "Only the decimal-constant, octal-constant, and hexadecimal-constant constants specified in the ISO C standard, Section 6.4.4.1 are required to be recognized as constants."   I believe the N# notation is a bashism.

Answer (score 0):

'#' will be interpreted as part of a token unless it is preceded by a space, newline, or semi-colon.
(or any other non-word symbol)

Section 2.3 "Token recognition" of the language spec, states:

```
 7. If the current character is an unquoted <newline>, the current
    token shall be delimited.
 8. If the current character is an unquoted <blank>, any token
    containing the previous character is delimited and the current
    character shall be discarded.
 9. If the previous character was part of a word, the current character
    shall be appended to that word.
10. If the current character is a '#' , it and all subsequent characters
    up to, but excluding, the next <newline> shall be discarded as
    a comment. The <newline> that ends the line is not considered
    part of the comment.
```

When the shell is parsing its input and reads "foo#bar", as it is processing the '#' character it applies rule 9 and appends the # to the token.  Once rule 9 is applied, it stops checking and rule 10 is never considered.  If the character preceding the '#' is whitespace, then rule 9 does not apply, so rule 10 is checked and a comment is started.

In other words, a '#' only starts a comment if the character preceded it is not part of a word ( eg whitespace or semi-colon), so "foo#bar" is one token, and not "foo" followed by a comment, but "foo #bar" is the token "foo" followed by a comment.